# How to configure @Component class appropriately

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a SqsQueueSender to send messages to AWS.  I want to test this class.  My thought is that it should be a `@Component` that is injected in to the classes that need it.  Importantly, I want to configure the endpoint of the `SqsQueueSender` to be different in testing vs. production environments.

I've been moving @Autowired and @Component around the classes various different ways but must have some basic misunderstanding.  Here's my latest configuration:

```
package com.foo.fulfillmentApi.dao;

import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClient;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

@Component
public class SqsQueueSender {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SqsQueueSender.class);
    private final QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;

    @Autowired
    AmazonSQSAsyncClient amazonSQSAsyncClient;

    //This value is from /resources/application.properties
    private @Value("${sqs.endpoint}") String endpoint;

    public SqsQueueSender(AmazonSQSAsyncClient amazonSqsAsyncClient) {
        amazonSqsAsyncClient.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        this.queueMessagingTemplate = new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqsAsyncClient);
    }

    public void send(String queueName, String message) {
        this.queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
    }
}
```

The error message on startup states

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClient' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}

To implement `SqsQueueSender` you must pass an `AmazonSQSAsyncClient`.  How do I make sure this component can access an existing bean of that type?

Comment: Dont know anything about aws. But where is `AmazonSQSAsyncClient` definition to be a bean?

Comment: If I understand your question, that class is not defined as a `@Bean` in my project. How do you create a @Bean from an existing class you've imported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a configuration class. In your case it would be something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AWSConfig {

   @Bean(name ="awsClient")
   public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSClient() {
     AmazonSQSAsyncClient awsSQSAsyncClient 
            = new AmazonSQSAsyncClient();

     // set up the client

     return awsSQSAsyncClient;
}
```

If it has problems with injecting then add qualifier in qsQueueSender:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("awsClient")
AmazonSQSAsyncClient amazonSQSAsyncClient;
```

You can also do this using the xml configuration but as you are using annotations then this is more advisable approach.

Comment: Thanks.  My app starts now.  I am still unable to run tests against the class that uses the `Client`.  How would I instantiate an instance of `SqsQueueSender` in my test class?

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles. Read the Integration Testing with @Configuration Classes section. Should be enough for you

Comment: I'm afraid it wasn't enough.  I've reposted the question with more details if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814498/how-to-configure-nested-dependency-for-spring-tests.  Thanks again, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Component/@Service in com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClient or return an object of that using @Bean annotation from configuration class.

Comment: Re: "return an object of that using @Bean annotation from configuration class."  Does that mean to create a class annotated with @Bean that describes how to construct an `AmazonSQSAsyncClient`?  If AmazonSQSAsyncClient is a concrete class, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use springboot - define into your startup application file as below

```
@Bean
    public AmazonSNSAsync amazonSNSClient() {
        ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
        return AmazonSNSAsyncClient.asyncBuilder().withClientConfiguration(config)
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName(region))
                .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .build();

    }
```